# how to insert counter in python

Tags: python, math, numpy

```
outfile2 = open('cordrandm.pdb', 'w')
for kk in text1:
if kk != '':
    outfile2.write(kk)
    outfile2.write('\n')

for alcord in alistcoord:
    uacoord = alcord[1]
    for blcord in blistcoord:
        ubcoord = blcord[1]    
        for arang in range(1000):
            arang = arang + 1
            x,y,z = uacoord
            x1,y1,z1 = (uniform(x-3.5,x+3.5), uniform(y-3.5,y+3.5), uniform(z-3.5,z+3.5))
            pacord = [x1,y1,z1]

            dist_pap = euDist(uacoord, pacord)
            if  3.5 > dist_pap > 2.5: 
               dist_pap1 = dist_pap

    outfile2.write('ATOM         OW  HOH X          %6.3f  %6.3f  %6.3f\n' % (pacord[0],  pacord[1],  pacord[2]))

outfile2.close()
```

From this code i am getting output file like this

```
1------10 11-----20 21------30-----so on
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
ATOM         OW  HOH X          10.533  22.567  61.777
ATOM         OW  HOH X           5.655  23.758  61.221
ATOM         OW  HOH X          10.125  20.476  68.503
ATOM         OW  HOH X          11.222  16.810  69.267
ATOM         OW  HOH X           4.351  18.904  66.256
ATOM         OW  HOH X           9.194  22.065  67.714
ATOM         OW  HOH X           4.347  16.527  68.278
```

i want to insert counter for each row 'HOH' and output like this

```
ATOM         OW  HOH X   1      10.533  22.567  61.777
ATOM         OW  HOH X   2       5.655  23.758  61.221
ATOM         OW  HOH X  10      10.125  20.476  68.503
ATOM         OW  HOH X 100      11.222  16.810  69.267
ATOM         OW  HOH X 101       4.351  18.904  66.256
ATOM         OW  HOH X 102       9.194  22.065  67.714
ATOM         OW  HOH X1000       4.347  16.527  68.278
```

means column range 23-26 specify the serial number of HOH.
How i Will insert count for HOH in the specific column which do not change my output fromat.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Exactly like in your last question about the pacord.. Just change the line to:

`outfile2.write('ATOM         OW  HOH X%4s      %6.3f  %6.3f  %6.3f\n' % (hoh_serial, pacord[0],  pacord[1],  pacord[2]))`

(considering `hoh_serial` contains the serial for that row)

**EDIT**

And if you meant really a serial number for the row then you should also add:

```
from itertools import count
...
hoh_serial = count(1)
...
...
outfile2.write('ATOM         OW  HOH X%4s      %6.3f  %6.3f  %6.3f\n' % (hoh_serial.next(), pacord[0],  pacord[1],  pacord[2]))
```

Comment: thanks Ofir Israel. As I am beginner. How I can specify each column in my out file.

Comment: What? :) I don't understand

Comment: like i want to specify each column. Like 1-6 for ATOM, then 13-16 for OW, 18-20 for HOH, 21 is space, 22 for X, 23-26 for serial number, 31-38 for pcord[0], 39-46 for pcord[1], 37-57 for pcord[2]. This is standard format of PDB file.

Comment: And the rest are spaces?

Comment: yes rest are the spaces. I am struggling past 2 days to write such format and save my output. In this script I generated xyz coordinates of HOH, and do do not define ATOM, OW, HOH and X anywhere because this is common.

Comment: You can do this in numerous ways:
1) Using string.format (http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)
2) Using string.Template
3) Using your own function that builds this string
4) Using a class which you can override it's __str__() function to build this string
5) Lots more...

Comment: Thanks Ofir Israel. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
for counter, blcord in enumerate(blistcoord):
    ...
    outfile2.write('ATOM ...', (counter,...) )
```

and then counter is your counter.